# How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly brackets

Tags: equations, best-practices

I want to write a conditional expression such as the following.

[image]

What is the best way to express such conditional expressions in Latex?

Comment: use `cases` or `dcases`.

Answer (score 305, accepted):

I think this is a job for `cases` from the `amsmath` package

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
    f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    \frac{x^2-x}{x},& \text{if } x\geq 1\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

or if you would prefer a `displaystyle` fraction, then you could use `dcases` from the `mathtools` package, which extends (and loads) the `amsmath` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
    f(x)= 
\begin{dcases}
    \frac{x^2-x}{x},& \text{if } x\geq 1\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had thought you usually want a `\,` before text punctuation inline with math, no?

Comment: Is it possible to change the curly braces to bracket in this environment?

Answer (score 50):

Just for the sake of completeness (i.e. environments where `amsmath` may not be available): There is a pseudo-parenthesis `.` that can be used to terminate an opening parenthesis:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}

$\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{ c l }
    \frac{x^2 - x}{2} & \quad \textrm{if } x \geq 1 \\
    0                 & \quad \textrm{otherwise}
  \end{array}
\right.$

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You should expand this answer to show how to use this to produce the output in the original image.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Well, there are ways, but `cases` and `dcases` are much much more suitable for this task. Are there conditions where these environments are not available?

Comment: I actually like your answer better.

Comment: I like this answer for its flexibility. It shows how to create a single-sided brace (or any other grouping symbol) for applications where `cases` isn't suitable.

Comment: @krlmlr I have found environments where I don't have access to the `amsmath` package, so expanding this to perform what the question asked for would certainly help me!