# Latex Brace Stack

Tags: math-mode, equations, vertical-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47170/how-to-write-conditional-equations-with-one-sided-curly-brackets)

So I'm trying to take notes in LaTeX and while I've been able to keep up with everything that's been thrown at me so far, one thing that took me for a loop was when the professor made a large right facing curly brace, with text stacked on top on the right of it and a single statement to the left and center of the curly brace.

Here's my photoshop rendering so that it is more clear:

[image]

Is it possible to do something like this in LaTeX, without too much difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php to fiddle with LaTeX equations.

You probably want something like this:

```
left to curl \left\{\begin{matrix}
first \\
second \\ 
42
\end{matrix}\right.
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, that was a lot simpler than I thought! And here I was delving into the multirow and bigdelim packages getting nothing but frustration.

Comment: Please notice that there's a standard LaTeX way how to make this, without `matrix` and `\left...\right`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47170/how-to-write-conditional-equations-with-one-sided-curly-brackets/47171#47171