# Tall curly brace

Tags: brackets, cases

I would like to put a tall (long) left curly bracket on the left side of the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
c: $\{$1, ..., n$\}$ $\rightarrow$ $\{$1, ..., n$\}$, such that

\hspace{20 mm}

\noindent
c($a_i$) = $a_{i+1}$ for 1 $\le$ $i$ < $l$

\hspace{20 mm}

\noindent
c($a_l$) = $a_1$


\end{document}
```

Please let me know if you can help. Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) perhaps you want the cases environment, as demonstrated (for example) in [How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly brackets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47170)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The following may be close to what you're looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
c \colon \{1, \dots, n\} \rightarrow \{1, \dots, n\} \text{ such that}\\    
\begin{cases}
  c(a_i) = a_{i+1} & \text{for }1\le i<l\\    
  c(a_l) = a_1    
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Some comments:

- Use the `cases` environment, provided by the `amsmath` package, to place a left curly brace ahead of two or more expressions.
- Don't use `...` to create a typographical ellipsis; instead, use `\dots`.
- Use the `\text{ }` command to write text material inside mathematical expressions.
- As pointed out in the comments by @SvendTveskæg and @daleif, it's better (typographically speaking) to use the command `\colon` instead of `:`.

---

On the other hand, if you need the left-hand curly brace to span *all three* rows, you could do so with the following code:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
  c \colon \{1, \dots, n\} \rightarrow \{1, \dots, n\} \text{ such that}\\      
  c(a_i) = a_{i+1}  \text{ for $1\le i<l$}\\
  c(a_l) = a_1
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Observe, though, that this code doesn't make full use of the capabilities of the `cases` environment; for sure, one could replace `\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}` with a more basic `\left\{\begin{array}{@{}l} ... \end{array}\right.` construct.

Comment: Shouldn't you write ``\\`` to skip line, e.g. right after `such that` ?

Comment: @user130222 - Thanks for bringing the missing-double-backslash issue to my attention. There's been a most unfortunate site-wide software bug earlier this year, which "replaced" [!] lots and lots of (but weirdly not all) double-backslash instances with single-backslash instances. It's been a nightmare, honestly, to track down and fix all the postings affected by this bug. I hope it didn't trip you up too much. Again, thanks for bringing it to my attention; I've fixed the code (for now).

Answer (score 21):

Although the cases environment probably suits your needs best, I'd like to mention the more versatile and (probably) equivalent syntax `\left\{ <blank> \right\}`for future use, in case you haven't come across it.

Comment: It is not necessarily more versatile and not equivalent. This has been discussed quite a few times on this site, you can read more say in this one as it popped up first in the search http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208284/automatic-parenthesis-sizing-with-multiple-sums-and-products-using-new-lines

Comment: The method you're proposing has rather different syntax from the `cases` environment. The latter is designed for typesetting left-hand (result) and right-hand (conditioning information) material in a unified way. To mimic the syntax and structure of the `cases` environment using your setup, it would be necessary to define an interior `array` (or equivalent) environment as well.

Comment: Thanks folks, you're both right.  Since I've never used more than two 'cases', I guess I just assumed both methods were more or less equivalent.  And of course I also forgot to mention the need of `array`.

Comment: +1 thanks for mentioning that.  Not everyone on this site is a master at LaTeX.