# Automatic parenthesis sizing with multiple sums and products using new lines

Tags: brackets, sharelatex

I'm trying to use auto sizing of parentheses. Can you see why the below is creating brackets all of the same size? I've tried removing reference to the function `\x`, but this doesn't change anything. Is there a problem with using newlines and tabs to nicely display code like this?

**Note:** I'm using [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/) with no access to a LaTeX compiler atm.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, bm, amssymb}
% make bold x to the bracketed n (optional)
\newcommand{\x}[1][n]{\bm{x}^{\left(#1\right)}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \ell &= \prod_{n=1}^N \left[
        \sum_{k=1}^K \left[
            \pi_k \prod_{d=1}^D
                p_{kd}^{\x_d} \left(1-p_{kd}\right)^{1-\x_d}
        \right]
    \right]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I used `pdflatex`, the brackets and parentheses auto-expanded, so the problem is not with `\x` nor with the indentation. Perhaps it's a bug in ShareLaTeX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always desirable to use the controlled sizes offered by the `ams` package with sizes as: `\big, \Big, \bigg, \Bigg`. The reason here is that `\left` or `\right` only provides a single size bigger than a normal brace or bracket. For a comparison of the above sizes, see this picture, e.g.:

[image]

So, in your case you can do this as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, bm, amssymb}
% make bold x to the bracketed n (optional)
\newcommand{\x}[1][n]{\bm{x}^{\left(#1\right)}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \ell &= \prod_{n=1}^N \Biggl[
        \sum_{k=1}^K \biggl[
            \pi_k \prod_{d=1}^D
                p_{kd}^{\x_d} \left(1-p_{kd}\right)^{1-\x_d}
        \biggr]
    \Biggr]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Refer to the `ams` package [documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) for more details:

The output then is proportional as this:

[image]