# How to typeset piecewise-defined functions?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, cases

I am attempting to write out the basic process for finding the absolute value of some number.

In ASCII, this is what I am attempting to write.

```
|X| = {
        x  if x > 0
        0  if x = 0
        -x if x < 0
      }
```

This is what I have so far.

```
\begin{equation}
\left|x\right| = \biggl\{ x\ if\ x > 0 \biggr\}
\end{equation}
```

I cannot figure out how to add the vertical spacing to allow the other two lines.

Comment: Welcome to the site! have you looked at the `cases` environment? have you seen [How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly brackets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47170)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The OP ask for a two-sided curly brackets.

Comment: I've never seen the right brace in cases like this.

Comment: It is a duplicate, seeing what answer has been accepted.

Comment: Then I take that back, it is a duplicate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Option 1 (recommended)

left aligned

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\[
\lvert x \rvert =
\begin{cases}
x & \text{if } x>0\\
0 & \text{if } x=0\\
-x& \text{if } x<0
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Option 2 (just for fun)

right aligned

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\[
\lvert x \rvert =
\left\{
\!
\begin{aligned}
x & \text{ if } x>0\\
0 & \text{ if } x=0\\
-x& \text{ if } x<0
\end{aligned}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Important Notes

`standalone` class and `\abovedisplayskip=0pt` are settings for my own purpose to create a standalone and tight output. You should not use it for your production unless your objective is the same as mine.

Comment: There's no need to drop use of the `cases` environment just because you might want to typeset the contents of the first column flush-right. Just write `\hill x` and `\hfill 0` instead of `x` and `0`.

Comment: @Mico: Yes. It is a just-for-fun option. Thanks.

Comment: A real disadvantage of using the `aligned` environment (at least in the way you've implemented it in your example code) instead of the `cases` environment for the purpose at hand is that you get inferior horizontal spacing between the first and second columns.

Comment: Please, make clear in your answer that `\abovedisplayskip=0pt` is a setting just for the examples.

Answer (score 0):

Using the beta version of my `tabstackengine` package presented at [Writing a table with equally spaced columns, based on the widest column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139771/writing-a-table-with-equally-spaced-columns-based-on-the-widest-column/139946#139946), I can give you a number of configurable options on the appearance of the output.  First, I give it with the package default spacings.  Then I show how the horizontal gap can be increased in the stack, and finally how the interline spacing can be increased.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
\vert X\vert = \left\{
\alignVectorstack{
&x &\mathrm{if~} & x > 0\\
&0 &\mathrm{if~} & x = 0\\
&-x&\mathrm{if~} & x < 0
}
\right.
\]
\setstackaligngap{3em}
\[
\vert X\vert = \left\{
\alignVectorstack{
&x &\mathrm{if~} & x > 0\\
&0 &\mathrm{if~} & x = 0\\
&-x&\mathrm{if~} & x < 0
}
\right.
\]
\setstackgap{L}{1.4\baselineskip}
\[
\vert X\vert = \left\{
\alignVectorstack{
&x &\mathrm{if~} & x > 0\\
&0 &\mathrm{if~} & x = 0\\
&-x&\mathrm{if~} & x < 0
}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]