# Cases for defining a math function

Tags: math-mode

Sometimes in mathematics, when defining a function, I see something like

```
f(x) = 0 if x is even
       1 if x is odd
```

where an open brace is used in front of the values 0 and 1. How can I do that in LaTeX?

Comment: you'll need the `cases` environment from `amsmath` or perhaps `dcases` from `mathtools`; have a look at [How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly brackets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47170) for example- there are lots of others on this site as well: search for `cases site:tex.stackexchange.com`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#The_cases_environment, which perfectly answers your question.

Remember to include the `amsmath` package in your preamble: `\usepackage{amsmath}`