# How to write conditional equations within equation tags

Tags: equations, texmaker

I used following tags to create equations in my document. But when I tried to add conditional equation within this tag, it didn't work properly. Is there any way to add conditional statement within equation tags?

```
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
         xxxxx, & \text{xxx}\\
         xxxxx, & \text{xxx}
     \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
```

Comment: like this? [How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly brackets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47170)

Comment: What exactly did you try? Can you edit-in the code you used?

Comment: @cmhughes, yes I want to add that kind of equation

Comment: So it can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @karlkoeller, I tried with that code, doesn't work for me when I added it within the equation tag.

Comment: Did you load `amsmath`, i.e. `\usepackage{amsmath}`?

Comment: @karlkoeller, no. is "\begin(cases)" belongs to amsmath? I'll try that.

Comment: To use it in that form, `amsmath` is required.

Comment: @karlkoeller, Oh! sorry.. Big mistake!. :) Now it works. Thank you very much