# How to get more space in piecewise function on LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I'm writing a paper and I have inserted a piecewise function into my tex-code. My problem is that the piecewise function is very tightly packed. How could I stretch the bracket and get more space between the formulas? See code and result below:

```
$$
\displaystyle{
P(Y_i = j) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{1}{1+\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}e^{\beta_k\cdot x_i}} & \quad k=K \\
            \frac{e^{\beta_j\cdot x_i}}{1+\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}e^{\beta_k\cdot x_i}} & \quad 1 \leq k \leq K-1
        \end{array}
    \right.,
    }
$$
```

[image]

Comment: I think that what you are looking for is the `cases` environment, as described in [How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly brackets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47171)

Comment: And also, do you perhaps mean `$P(Y_{i=j})$`? I've just never seen notation such as it is currently (with my limited exposure).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `$$` for display math.

`\displaystyle` is not needed.

## Option -1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
P(Y_i = j) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{1}{1+\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}e^{\beta_k\cdot x_i}} & \quad k=K \\[1em]
            \frac{e^{\beta_j\cdot x_i}}{1+\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}e^{\beta_k\cdot x_i}} & \quad 1 \leq k \leq K-1
        \end{array}
    \right.,
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Option - 2

You can use cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
P(Y_i = j) = \begin{cases}
            \frac{1}{1+\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}e^{\beta_k\cdot x_i}} & \quad k=K \\[1em]   %%% <--- here
            \frac{e^{\beta_j\cdot x_i}}{1+\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}e^{\beta_k\cdot x_i}} & \quad 1 \leq k \leq K-1
        \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

In either case, you can use `\\[<dimen>]` to change the vertical separation.

## Beautification

To make your `sum`s to look less cramped, you can use `\limits` as in

```
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K-1}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
P(Y_i = j) = \begin{cases}
            \frac{1}{1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K-1}e^{\beta_k\cdot x_i}} & \quad k=K \\[2em]
            \frac{e^{\beta_j\cdot x_i}}{1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K-1}e^{\beta_k\cdot x_i}} & \quad 1 \leq k \leq K-1
        \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ehm `cases` ehm

Comment: if you are loading amsmath anyway you could use the cases environment which is specifically for this use.

Comment: @tohecz I didn't finish yet. Options are on way :-)

Comment: @HarishKumar However, by that time, the OP will very likely leave, using quite not as good solution as he could.

Comment: @tohecz I am slow ;-). Now I am finished. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I had no idea that `amsmath` had such a useful redefinition, so that should be the correct answer (after use of `cases`).  However, for completeness (or if you want more space) you have a few options:

- reformulate your terms to allow for more vertical leg-room
- modify `\arraystretch` to a desired scale (but will cause potentially awkward space on top)
- use a strut, as in the example below:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{array}

  %\renewcommand\arraystretch{4}

  \begin{document}
  \[
  P(Y_i = j) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}ll}
      \biggl(1+\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}e^{\beta_k\cdot x_i}\biggr)^{-1}
      & \quad k=K \\
      \biggl(1+\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}e^{\beta_k\cdot x_i}\biggr)^{-1}
      e^{\beta_j\cdot x_i}
      & \quad 1 \leq k \leq K-1

      \rule{0pt}{8ex} % called a 'strut' -- a vertical rule of nil width
    \end{array}
    \right.,
  \]
  \end{document}
  ```

  [image: output]

Comment: No, this is wrong. The parentheses are too large. Try `\biggl(...\biggr)` instead of `\left(...\right)`, please. After all, why `\displaystyle` when `\textstyle would fit there much better? Anyways, +1 for getting rid of the fractions.

Comment: @tohecz Ah, yes - `\left` and `\right` don't take the limits into account very well... And personally, while I haven't much of a leg to stand on as for conventions, if you're going to have a large cases like this, it should be `\display`ed, not so cramped as in `\textstyle`. Just personal preference probably prejudiced by handwritten math `:)`

Answer (score 4):

The `dcases` environment by »[mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)« from the »[mh](http://ctan.org/pkg/mh)« bundle seems to be quite handy here.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % loads »amsmath«

\begin{document}
  \[
    P(Y_i=j)=
    \begin{dcases}
      \frac{1}{1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K-1}e^{\beta_k\cdot x_i}} & \quad k=K \\
      \frac{e^{\beta_j\cdot x_i}}{1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K-1}e^{\beta_k\cdot x_i}} & \quad 1 \leq k \leq K-1
    \end{dcases}
  \]
\end{document}
```

---

[image]