# How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly bracket in TeXmacs

Tags: math-mode, texmacs

Here is the photo. How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly bracket in TeXmacs?

[image]

I tried inserting Equation and Equations.   I didn't manage to insert the curly bracket.
In LaTeX, it's like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
    f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    \frac{x^2-x}{x},& \text{if } x\geq 1\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the question? Your code produces exactly what you have in picture. What else is needed?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The code is for LaTeX, I would like to implement it in TeXmacs.

Comment: reference: [How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly brackets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47170)

Comment: @cmhughes - It would appear that the OP has lifted the code of his/her example straight from your old posting. However, the main issue appears to be something else: How to compile this example in `texmacs`, a program (or TeX distribution?) I'm not familiar with.

Comment: I've solved it by myself, thanks guys! Due to time limitation, I have to paste my answer several hours later, it might help the followers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about TeXmacs which is a different program not connected to TeX and friends, although it shares some parts of the syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved it by myself.

In equation mode you can click on `Insert a table` in the tool bar, then choose `Choice`, grid with with one-sided curly bracket will be automatically generated.

[image: solve]

Comment: This helps me! Great!