# Typesetting the definition of a piecewise function

Tags: math-mode

How to write this in LaTeX:

```
y = {1 if a >b
     0 if a <b
```

How to make the big bracket that contains both and defines the function y?

Comment: The `cases` environment is what you should looking for. For example [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#The_cases_environment).

Comment: Your title could be a *little* more descriptive. `:-)`

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47170/how-to-write-conditional-equations-with-one-sided-curly-brackets