# Two conditional equations in the same line

Tags: equations

I want to define two functions conditionally as in [How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47170/how-to-write-conditional-equations-with-one-sided-curly-brackets), but I want to write the two equations on the same line. Is there a way for this?

[image]

Comment: Two cases environment in an align environment should do it, if I've understood well what you want.

Comment: @Bernard I added a picture what I want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No further special constructs are needed for this, just add some space after the first definition with e.g. `\qquad`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  w_{n}(x) =
  \begin{dcases*}
    \frac{1}{2^{n+1}(1+\mu(E_{n}))},&if \( x\in E_{n}\),\\
    0,&otherwise,
  \end{dcases*}
  \qquad
  u_{n}(x) =
  \begin{dcases*}
    \frac{\mu(E_{n})}{2^{n+1}(1+\mu(E_{n}))},&if \( x\in E_{n}\),\\
    0,&otherwise.
  \end{dcases*}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

If a `\qquad` is too much, you can reduce to a `\quad`.
It is best to make the punctuation part of the cases statements, rather than putting it outside these blocks.