# Align equation left after curly bracket

Tags: math-mode, mathjax

I'm looking for a way to align on the left side my math formula and on the right side the `\textrm` part.

```
\begin{equation}
w_{t} = \Bigg\{
\begin{aligned}
\log(y_{t}) \textrm{ if } \lambda = 0; \\
(y_{t}^{\lambda} - 1)/ \lambda \textrm{ otherwise }
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Is there a simple solution to achieve that ?

Comment: See [How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47170/5764); essentially, use `cases` provided by [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

Comment: ...is this specific to MathJax? If so, the suggestion above still holds. See [this output on Math.SE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp2Iy.png).

Comment: Yes, it helps a lot, thanks for your answers ! (I figured that `ansmath` works with MathJax)