# How can I type this formula in LaTex

Tags: math-mode, equations, unicode-math, mathtools

![[image: How can I type this formula in LaTex]]
I'm writing my thesis and I need help on how I can type the following equation in LaTex.

Comment: Hi, welcome. I think https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47170/how-to-write-conditional-equations-with-one-sided-curly-brackets/47171#47171 will answer your question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The `cases` environment is done for that.